# setSearchDisplayController considered private-API?

Tags: iphone

I recently submitted an app for app review but I got rejected because of the use of a private API. I'm still a bit new to iPhone developing so I was wondering if someone could help me understand how this part was rejected:

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 0)] autorelease];
searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
searchBar.placeholder = @"Search Exhibitors";
[searchBar sizeToFit];

[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:searchBar];

UISearchDisplayController *searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];  

[self performSelector:@selector(setSearchDisplayController:) withObject:searchDisplayController];

[searchDisplayController setDelegate:self];  
[searchDisplayController setSearchResultsDataSource:self];  
[searchDisplayController setSearchResultsDelegate:self];
[searchDisplayController release];
```

The part that they mentioned was the "setSearchDisplayController". I based the searching of a UITableView on the example given [here](http://blog.originalfunction.com/index.php/2010/02/uitableviewcontroller-with-uisearchdisplaycontroller-for-core-data/). So can anyone explain why this is considered a private API?

Answer (score 1):

Is `-setSearchDisplayController:` mentioned anywhere in the documentation (I don't think it is)?
If it is not then it's not a public API.

The fact that you have to use `-performSelector:withObject:` and can't call it directly is another giveaway. `-setSearchDisplayController` obviously isn't included in any header files.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self performSelector:@selector(setSearchDisplayController:) withObject:searchDisplayController];
```

Is a private API call and it can cause an app rejection by Apple, I know because it happened to an app I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's UIViewController doc:

> @property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UISearchDisplayController
>   *searchDisplayController
> This property reflects the value of the searchDisplayController outlet that you set in Interface Builder. If
>   you create your search display controller programmatically, this
>   property is set automatically by the search display controller when it
>   is initialized.