# How to create an ivar for searchDisplayController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, searchdisplaycontroller, ivar

following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059506/setsearchdisplaycontroller-considered-private-api) question, how would I create an "ivar" as mentioned?  Ran into this same issue and I'm trying to work around it so apple will approve my latest update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the header file:

```
@interface MyClass : Superclass {
     UISearchDisplayController *mySearchDisplayController;
}
```

In the implementation:

```
mySearchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
```

And in -dealloc:

```
[mySearchDisplayController release];
```

Comment: instead of alloc can I do a full property w/ @synth and dealloc?

Comment: Yep! Just as long as you're defining your own accessor/mutator (via @synthesize) and not using private API.