# UISearchDisplayController retain cycle

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a very strange problem and I cannot find a solution. In one of my apps I need to create a `UISearchDisplayController` programatically. I am creating it in a subclass of `UITableViewController`. And I run into a very simple problem - my search display controller either gets released immediately OR it causes the retain cycle and prevents its contents controller from getting released.

In my `viewDidLoad` method I instantiate my `UISearchDisplayController` with this code:

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
sC = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
self.searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
```

If `sC` is defined as a property or instance variable in my view controller, search controller works, but it prevents `dealloc` method of my view controller from being called. If, however, `sC` is defined as the variable only within `viewDidLoad` method, my view controller gets deallocated fine, but `self.searchDisplayController` becomes `nil` almost instantly and search doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to solve this? I have already tried overriding the `searchDisplayController` property - it doesn't help.

I should probably mention that I am using ARC. Also, when I say that "`dealloc` isn't called" I mean that I have an `NSLog` statement there which doesn't get printed.

## Update

As some users suggested that there is already an answer and that simply overriding the `searchDisplayController` property should work I post below what I did (which didn't work).

I added a property to my subclass of `UITableViewController`:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) UISearchDisplayController *searchDisplayController;
```

In my `viewDidLoad` I initialised my search controller:

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
self.searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
```

In the `dealloc` method of my view controller I have:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"dealloc");
    self.searchDisplayController = nil;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Line "dealloc" doesn't get printed and if I profile with instruments my view controller is not getting released.

I have also tried adding other properties with different name - it still doesn't get deallocated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIViewController does not retain its programmatically-created UISearchDisplayController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679501/uiviewcontroller-does-not-retain-its-programmatically-created-uisearchdisplaycon)

Comment: @dopcn No it is not, because as I said in the question, I know how to retain it. The problem is that if I do I cannot release it. Read more carefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have figured it out. In order for dealloc to be called on the view controller which initialises the `UISearchDisplayController` I had to do this:

At the top of .m file add the following:

```
static UISearchDisplayController *sC;
```

Then in viewDidLoad initialise the search controller like this:

```
    if (sC==nil) {
        UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        sC = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
    }
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    self.searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
```

And then in the `dealloc` method do the following:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    sC = nil;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

And now it all works great. Search controller is working fine and everything gets deallocated as it should :)

Comment: This is an old answer, but I have to say, you didn't use `sC` variable at all. So this is nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

haha have you ever go into that question I provided. So summary of that question's accepted answer:

1. use a property to hold your `UISearchDisplayController`
2. when the holder viewController is dealloc nil it out

   ```
   - (void)dealloc {
        self.searchDisplayController = nil;
   }
   ```
3. don't use `UIViewController`'s default property `searchDisplayController` it's broken

Comment: Yes I did and I have indicated in my question "Does anyone know how to solve this? I have already tried overriding the searchDisplayController property - it doesn't help.". Dealloc is still not getting called. Tested on iOS 8 and iOS 9